# Biological Themodynamics - What does an endpoint saturated signal mean. How does it relate to equillibrium constant

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, biology

I have had a question that has been bugging me for a couple of years in my graduate school career, and I was wondering if perhaps some physicist could help explain it to me. Given an endpoint assay like this one  I've shown below (an ELISA assay, but I assume it could work for any endpoint), how does the endpoint signal (the signal at the highest concentration) relate to binding. And how does EC50 (the concentration between the maximum and minmum signal) relate to the equillibrium constant.

[ELISA http://structbio.vanderbilt.edu/~willisjr/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-17%20at%2012.19.53%20PM.jpg](http://structbio.vanderbilt.edu/~willisjr/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-17%20at%2012.19.53%20PM.jpg)

For years, biologist have used the EC50 to give a rough approximation for the equilibrium binding constant $K_d$. However, it always bothered me that all curves features on the graph could produce nearly the same EC50, but with different levels of maximum absorbance. For instance two of the curves are saturated at around 1.2 and the others are around 2.5.

Do all of these curves have roughly the same $K_d$, or is it worrisome that we don't get equivalence signal for the maximum concentrations.

Please note, I was not sure whether this belongs in biology or physics as its definitely a biologic assay but the principals I'm asking about are physics oriented.

Thanks

Comment: Where biology and physics meet, there is http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ to consider. At the very least, most physicists are not on a day-to-day familiarity with assays, so the definitions of absorbance and $K_d$ might be needed.

Comment: Hello I will do that. Using an ELISA, the absorbance is the signal you receive that is directly related to how much complex you have. As you dilute the mixture the absorbance goes down because less complex is formed. Kd is the equilibrium constant that is the ratio of bound/unbound. Ex, A 10^-9 Kd would indicate that 1 molecule is unbound for every 1 billion that are bound at equilibrium.